# Event subscription when entering data to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, rds, serverless-framework

I am using "serverless" framework (AWS lambda functions and RDS database). When inserting data to RDS database, I also want to insert it into Algolia database (to sync the two databases), is it possible to call a lambda function when a record is inserted into RDS? (maybe event subscription?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only supported for AWS RDS aurora databases.

lets read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/capturing-data-changes-in-amazon-aurora-using-aws-lambda/) article.